# Trouble assigning multiple classes to tables

Tags: html, css, border, css-tables

I'm using multiple tables with different properties. The problem is all of my tables seem to be get their properties from the one class, "spectable". Particularly the border, I don't want borders in any other class. How to I properly assign multiple tables?

HTML

```
/*I only need a table here to keep it centered in the page, so i want no border*/ 
<table class="bantable">
<tr>
<td align="middle">
<div id="container">     
    <!-- Each image is 350px by 233px -->  
    <div class="photobanner">
        <img class="first" src="/banner/AA.JPG" alt="">
        <a target="_blank" href="P1010011.JPG">
    </div>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>

/*this one i want the border in*/
<table class="spectable">
  <tr>
    <th>Type</th>
    <td>GMC 7000 Dump Truck</td>
  <tr>
    <th>Stock#</th>
    <td>70017</td>
    <th>Condition</th>
    <td>N/A</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
</table>
```

CSS

```
table.bantable  table, td, th, tr
{
  border: none;
}

table.spectable  table, td, th 
{
  border: 3px solid #fdff30;
}

table.spectable th 
{
  background-color: #fdff30;
  color: black;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you used the td, th, table selector was wrong. Update your CSS like below.

```
 table.bantable, table.bantable td, table.bantable th, table.bantable tr
 {
  border: none;
 }

 table.spectable, table.spectable td, table.spectable th 
 {
   border: 3px solid #fdff30;
  }

 table.spectable th 
 {
   background-color: #fdff30;
   color: black;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks. P.S  my post was edited. I mentioned i researched the best i could before posting something that was covered 1,000 times before, and i appreciate the help from everyone on this site. I will keep those comments out next time and try to be more concise. Except for this comment. lol.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are using commas in your selectors.

Look at this fiddle for an example of how it was changed: http://jsfiddle.net/6GVRr/

```
table.bantable td, table.bantable th, table.bantable tr
{
  border: none;
}

table.spectable td, table.spectable th 
{
  border: 3px solid #fdff30;
}

table.spectable th 
{
  background-color: #fdff30;
  color: black;
}
```